# Axios interceptor request to refresh id token when expired in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, interceptor

I want to use axios interceptor before every axios call to pass idToken as  authorization header with all the axios calls and I want to refresh the idToken if it has expired before any call.

I am using the following code:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  var idToken = getIdToken()
  var refreshToken = {
    "refreshToken" : getRefreshToken()
  }

   if(isTokenExpired(idToken)){
     console.log("==============Reloading")
     refresh(refreshToken).then(response=>{
       setIdToken(response.idToken)
       setAccessToken(response.accessToken)
     })
     idToken = getIdToken()
     config.headers.Authorization = `${idToken}`;
   }
   else{
    config.headers.Authorization = `${idToken}`;
   }
 return config;
 }, function(err) {
  return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

It works fine till the time idToken is valid. When the idToken expires it gets in an infinite loop and the page hangs. Please help me with this. The refresh() which call the refresh API looks like this:

```
function refresh(refreshToken) {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/user/refresh`;
  return axios.post(url,JSON.stringify(refreshToken))
  .then(response =>response.data.data)
  .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe try a [different axios instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) for regular requests and a separate one for refreshes?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Still this thing turns into an infinite loop.

Comment: In what file do you keep that code? Or where in the project?

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar problem and creating new axios instance to perform refresh token api call resolved the problem (new AXIOS instance is not resolved by defined axios.interceptors.request.use) (of course below code is just a simple example).

Remember to save original request and process it after token has been refreshed:

F.ex my http-common.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const AXIOS = axios.create()
export default AXIOS
```

...

in App.vue:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  let originalRequest = config
  if (helper.isTokenExpired(this.$store.getters.tokenInfo)) {
    return this.refreshToken(this.$store.getters.jwt).then((response) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
      originalRequest.headers.Authorization = response.data.token
      return Promise.resolve(originalRequest)
    })
  }
  return config
}, (err) => {
  return Promise.reject(err)
})
```

and the refresh token method:

```
    refreshToken (token) {
      const payload = {
        token: token
      }
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return AXIOS.post('/api/auth/token/refresh/', payload, { headers: headers }).then((response) => {
          resolve(response)
        }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error)
        })
      })
    }
  }
```